# Try to setup autoinstall in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS booting through iso and use https://x.x.x.x./user-data to install unattended in VM not working

Tags: grub2, cloud-init, autoinstall

*Autoinstall* skips after searching for *cloud-init* and drops back to manual install interactive menu. Why is it not picking up the `user-data` file?

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

I am trying to boot by editing grub:

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud-net; s=https://x.x.x.x/ubuntu/
```

And then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot the install using above parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't included your `user-data` file, so I'm not sure if you have a problem with that. However, based on what you have supplied, your grub entry has two problems:

1. Although required, you have a semi-colon after `ds=nocloud-net`, which means grub will treat the rest of the line as a comment. So you have to either escape it with a `\` or put the value in quotes.
2. You have a space after the semi-colon and before `s=https://x.x.x.x/ubuntu/`

Try this...

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=https://x.x.x.x/ubuntu/ ---
```

Or ...

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz autoinstall "ds=nocloud;s=https://x.x.x.x/ubuntu/" ---
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its the problem with quotes the  'ds=nocloud;s=https://x.x.x.x/ubuntu/' need single quotes between the ds and the end of the file and the autoinstall worked, thanks I have solved it already

Comment: I am not sure how your line starting with `linux` finally was.  Could you post it completely, please?

Comment: Hi! This is not really an answer, rather a confirmation that [mpboden's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1487765/618353) worked for you. Instead of posting an answer confirming it, can you please accept mpboden's answer as the solution by clicking the gray checkmark next to it? Thank you!

Comment: Yes it worked after adding single quotes, thanks